# Scan a two dimensional array mirrored and rotated

Tags: arrays

I need to scan a rectangular 2-dimensional array. Normally, I would use a nested loop over y and x. However, I also want to scan the array in a rotated and/or mirrored fashion. Naively, that would lead to 2 * 4 = 8 nested loops, which I would like to avoid.

How would I elegantly implement all 8 cases?

This is what I came up with:

```
int sx = 3;
int sy = 2;
var a = new int [,] {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
};

for (int order = 0; order < 8; order++) {
    var mirrorX = (order & 1) != 0;
    var mirrorY = (order & 2) != 0;
    var mirrorDiag = (order & 4) != 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sx * sy; i++) {
        int x = mirrorDiag ? i % sx : i / sy;
        int y = mirrorDiag ? i / sx : i % sy;
        if (mirrorX) {
            x = sx - x - 1;
        }
        if (mirrorY) {
            y = sy - y - 1;
        }
        Console.Write (a [y, x]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine ();
}
```

> 142536
>   362514
>   415263
>   635241
>   123456
>   321654
>   456123
>   654321

Comment: It was downvoted, but I wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend you split this task into two parts:

1. Create `Deque` for each *row* and *column*. In your example you will have 2 *horizontal* queues and 3 *vertical* queues.
2. As now you have new data you need, do create 8 separated functions (i.e. strategies) of traversing these queues.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is simpler than naively creating 8 nested loops. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Couple questions before: you int value could be more that 1 digit? As output you would like to have a String or List<Integer>?

Comment: There is additional logic at the place where the content of an x-y coordinate is read. The `Console.WriteLine` was just an example.